# User I/O using the keyboard and display registers

Tags: string, output

I'm trying to take in user input and have the console print out the input after the user has pressed the ENTER key.

Any ideas or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Here's what outputs:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWhIA.png)

```
.ORIG x3000
LEA  R3, MEM ; Load memory block into R3
LD R2, LINE

LOOP LDI R0, KBSR ; Load the value of the KBSR into R0
  BRzp LOOP ; If KBSR[15] = 0, no key has been pressed  
  LDI R0, KBDR ; Copy the waiting character from the KBDR to R0
  LDI R3, KBDR ; copy the wating character into R3

LOOP2 LDI R1, DSR ; Load the value of the DSR into R1  
  BRzp LOOP2 ; If DSR[15] = 0, the display is not ready
  ADD R2, R0, #-10 ; checks to see if Enter key was pressed
  BRz DISPLAY ; if so go to display characters
  BRnp LOOP

DISPLAY  STI R3, DDR ; Copy the character in R0 to the Data display    register
  PUTS
  ADD R3, R3, #1 ; update storage location.

HALT

DSR .FILL xFE04
DDR .FILL xFE06
KBSR .FILL xFE00
KBDR .FILL xFE02
MEM .BLKW 64
LINE .FILL #10
.END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the modified code; this will take some input from the user and the print it out to the console using only the I/O registers.

The lines with comments are the lines of code I added.

.

```
.ORIG x3000

    LEA R3, MEM 
    LD R2, LINE
LOOP    
    LDI R0, KBSR 
    BRzp LOOP 

    LDI R0, KBDR
    STR R0, R3, #0      ; Store R0 into the mem location in R3
    ADD R3, R3, #1      ; Increment our pointer to the next block of mem
LOOP2 
    LDI R1, DSR 
    BRzp LOOP2 
    ADD R2, R0, #-10 
    BRz DISPLAY 
    BRnp LOOP 
DISPLAY
    LEA R3, MEM         ; reset our pointer back to the start of MEM
DISPLAY2                ; create a second label because we don't want
                        ; to load MEM into R3 each time we loop
    LDI R1, DSR         ; Load the display status register
    BRzp DISPLAY2       ; If the console is busy, loop again
    LDR R2, R3, #0      ; load the value at mem[R3] into R2
    BRz END             ; Check to see if we're at the end of the string
    STI R2, DDR         ; store the value of R2 into DDR
    ADD R3, R3, #1
    BR DISPLAY2         ; Keep looping until all char have been printed
END
    HALT

DSR .FILL xFE04
DDR .FILL xFE06
KBSR    .FILL xFE00
KBDR    .FILL xFE02

LINE    .FILL #10
MEM .BLKW 64

.END
```

Comment: This is beautiful, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the LC-3 simulator is printing out garbage is because of the way the `PUTs` command is being used. `PUTs` uses the value stored in R0 as a pointer to a memory location of a string.

In your example where you're pressing ENTER, **x000A** (decimal 10) is being stored into R0, when you use the `PUTs` at this point, it looks at memory location **x000A** for a string but ends up printing garbage. If you replace `PUTs` with `OUT` the code works fine.

Comment: If this was information you were looking for, please remember to mark this post as answered. Thanks.

Comment: Chris, 

I appreciate your help.

It no longer prints gibberish, instead it prints nothing, just skips to the next line and halts. Any other ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I see what you're saying, what exactly is your program supposed to do? If you can give me a description of how it's supposed to act I can help you better. As of right now it prints out the last char entered, and in this case that's the ENTER key.

Comment: Chris, Sorry for not being clear. It's supposed print out what the user types, a string in this case, after the ENTER key is pressed. I hope this clears it up a bit

Comment: No problem, and do you have to use the I/O registers? (ex. KBSR)

Comment: Yes, we had to extend a previously written piece of code.